# Graphical error while moving usercontrol (c# win7)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, user-controls

I am having trouble with painting usercontrol on form while moving the control.
The background of the control is shortened if moved to the right or downwards.

My control

```
public class DotPanel : Control
{
    public DotPanel() 
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow),new Rectangle(this.Location,this.Size));
    }
}
```

The main form just places the usercontrol on specified location and supplies the mouse down/move/up events to do the moving

Basicaly this>>

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseX = e.X;
        mouseY = e.Y;
        panelX = dp1.Left;
        panelY = dp1.Top;

        moving = true;
    }

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (moving)
        {
            dp1.Left = panelX + e.X - mouseX;
            dp1.Top = panelY + e.Y - mouseY;
            this.Invalidate(true);
        }
    }

 private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        moving = false;
        this.Invalidate(true);

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any clues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the overriden paint was the problem.
exchanging this.Size and this.Location for ClientRectangle.Size and ClientRectangle.Location worked...